# AddToAny reload after Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-waypoints

I have a website where I am switching from addThis to addToAny for social sharing buttons.  The problem is that the share buttons are contained in content that is loaded dynamically with jquery Waypoints infinite scroll feature (which uses Ajax).   When the page first loads (so no Ajax called yet) everything works great, but when a user scrolls and more content is added that contain the share buttons, the new buttons don't work in that they don't show the share options on hover or click.

There are supposedly fixes for this if using templates from the likes of Drupal or Wordpress, but my site is not built using any of these templates.  This was also a known issue with addThis, and to get around the problem you simply need to add 'addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox')' into the success portion of the ajax call and things would work.

I haven't had any success getting addToAny to work after ajax returns.  They have something that looked promising: a2a.init('page'), but that doesn't work.  Has anyone had this problem and have any suggestions on how to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: From AddToAny's FAQ
>How do I load the share buttons from an AJAX response?
>
>Check out [this document](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/multiple_buttons_customize)  which shows you how to best use multiple buttons on the same page. Call `a2a.init('page');` to initiate new share buttons.

Answer (score 4):

According to the AddToAny API (https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/api/), you should use `a2a.init_all();` if you are loading a number of new share button sets at once via AJAX.

Using `a2a.init('page');` only initializes the *last* uninitialized buttons instance on the page.  That might be fine for you, depending on how many new buttons that you load at a time.

Example: you have a blog site that loads new posts when the user scrolls to the end of the page.  If you are only loading one new set of share buttons for the new content, `a2a.init('page');` should work.  If instead, you are loading a few new posts at a time, that each get their own set of share buttons, you will want to use `a2a.init_all();`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

If there so many share button on one page you can call this after ajax success:

```
$(".a2a_dd").each(function() {
    a2a.init('page');
});
```

Or if there only one share button, you can use this after ajax success:

```
a2a.init('page');
```

If want to know more details go through [this document](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/multiple_buttons_customize)